# The type or namespace name could not be found

Tags: c#, xamarin, mono, gtk#

I am developing a cross-platform application using Mono and GTK# but i seem to get an error while trying to compile the app with Mono. Xamarin Studio generated a new namespace with the same title as the root one, the error i get is the following:

[image]

Here is the code of my MainWindows.cs file :

```
using System;
using Gtk;

public partial class MainWindow : Gtk.Window
{
public Ticket_Tracking.Search search;
public Ticket_Tracking.Update update;
public Ticket_Tracking.Add aadt;
    public MainWindow() : base(Gtk.WindowType.Toplevel)
    {
        Build();

        Gdk.Color col = new Gdk.Color();
        Gdk.Color.Parse("light blue", ref col);
        this.ModifyBg(Gtk.StateType.Normal, col);

        btnAdd.Clicked += btnAdd_clicked;
        btnUpdate.Clicked += btnUpdate_clicked;
    }


    protected void btnSearch_clicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        this.Hide();
        //Ticket_Tracking.Search search = new Ticket_Tracking.Search();

        search.Show();

    }

    protected void btnAdd_clicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {

        this.Hide();

        //Ticket_Tracking.Add addt = new Ticket_Tracking.Add();
        addt.Show();
    }
    protected void btnUpdate_clicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {

        this.Hide();

        //Ticket_Tracking.Update update = new Ticket_Tracking.Update();
        update.Show();
    }
    protected void OnDeleteEvent(object sender, DeleteEventArgs a)
    {
        Application.Quit();
        a.RetVal = true;

    }
}
```

The three public objects I used were automatically created by GTK# and are located in the User Interface folder . Does anybody know how can i fix this namespace problem or what should reference should I add?

Comment: Make sure Ticket_Tracking namespace exist

Comment: It's the local namespace that GTK# created , it's included in all the cs files except main window

Comment: how are you compiling this? and what are you telling the compiler to do?

Comment: I am compiling using mono, the command seen in the 1st image is used to build the project then create an exe file so that i can run it on mac. Also my compiler is set for debug

Answer (score 0):

Simple add the reference gdk-sharp (you are using the gdk.color - class !)